# How to setup CollectionView Layout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, layout, uicollectionview, snapchat

I am working with the `CollectionView`. I want `CollectionViewLayout` like below[image]

same as in `SnapChat` App `Discover Page` in Objective-c. Please Help me.

Comment: Define the logic of: "What's the size" for each item, how to calculate it. Then, we may help.

Comment: @Larme I don't know .No worries with the Item size layout want like that.

Comment: Check this [link](https://github.com/olxios/Custom-UICollectionView-Layout-Example)

Comment: Override `- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;` then. Put the size you want (maybe with calculation for the width according to `collectionView.frame.width`).

Comment: any thirdParty Libraries?

Comment: @Larme Thanks for pointing me But any thirdParty?

Comment: Thanks @Larme working fine. and i am looking for thirdParty but it is stupid idea for simple things now i realize thanks man.

Comment: If you want cells with different size in the same row, you'll need to use a Custom Flow Layout, you can check there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186246/uicollectionview-layout-like-snapchat