# How to achieve different number of columns for different rows in collection view

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionview, flowlayout

How can I achieve the layout shown in the image using the collection view?

[image]

I am trying to achieve it by using the waterfall flow layout from the below link but not getting success.
https://github.com/chiahsien/CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout

Below is the code by which I am trying to do so.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   let identifier = String(describing: collectionCell.self)
    collectionView.register("collectionCell", forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell")
    collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "collectionCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: identifier)
    let layout = CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    layout.minimumColumnSpacing = 10
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
}
```

//For setting the size of the cell

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let width = Double((self.collectionView.bounds.size.width-(4*minimumSpaceBetweenCells))/3)

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        return CGSize(width:width * 2, height: width * 2)
    }
    else
    {
        return CGSize(width:width, height: width)
    }

}
```

But it is just displaying the 2 columns with same size for all the rows.

Please let me know if anyone has idea how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you have to code the layout. See, the most of tutorials you find on internet, have either equal item height or width and variable width or height respectively. In your case you have 2 type of items with different height and width. You have to layout those items yourself.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186246/uicollectionview-layout-like-snapchat/43409440#43409440 ? Just calculate yourself the frames and it's easy.

Comment: Thanks @Larme I have created swift version from the link you provided and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a new tableView inside each collectionViewCell and set tableView's numberOfRows for the number of columns you want.