# CollectionView Flowlayout Customize

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

[image]

I am making a profile picture collectionview like tinder edit profile pictures. I want first cell bigger than others and 2, 3 cells besides first cell and others should like 3, 4, 5.
Any suggestion?

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        if indexPath.item == 0 {
        return CGSize(width: 213.34, height: 213.34)
        } else {
            return CGSize(width: 101.66, height:101.66 )
        }

    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 6
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        let lbl = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
        lbl.text = String(format: "%d", indexPath.row + 1)
        return cell
    }


}
```

Comment: Use stack view inside stack view

Comment: It should be dragable also.

Comment: your issue is that you need 3 below of 2?

Comment: can you provide the code of what you have so far?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k47D67a1zJ8

Comment: yes and instead of 3,4,5 it should be 4,5,6

Comment: Bigger image view for only first image?

Comment: That's normal behavior with `UICollectionViewLayout`, you need to subclass it (see there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186246/uicollectionview-layout-like-snapchat). I say normal behavior because it puts cell one after the other in a horizontal way, centering it (in vertical way speaking) according to the max height of the cells in the line, and when there is no more space horizontally it goes the next line. You currently give CGSize but not CGRect (Origin Point + CGSize).

Comment: @Jecky did my answer help you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to alig cell to top by Flow Layout in CollectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49055966/how-to-alig-cell-to-top-by-flow-layout-in-collectionview)

Answer (score 6):

You need to implement an `UICollectionViewLayout`, I had called it **FillingLayout**, Note that you can adjust the number of columns and the size of your big cells with the `delegate` methods

> **Explanation**

You need to add an Array to track your columns heigths and see what is the shortest column that is  `private var columsHeights : [CGFloat] = []` and you need also an array of `(Int,Float)` tuple to keep which spaces are available to be filled, I also added a method in the delegate to get the number of columns we want in the collection View and a method to know if a cell can be added or not in a position according their size.

Then if we want to add a cell we check if can be added if not, because the first column is filled we add the space corresponding to column2 in the avaiableSpaces array and when we add the next cell first we check if can be added in any available space if can be added we add and remove the available space.

**here is the full code**

```
import UIKit

protocol FillingLayoutDelegate: class {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView:UICollectionView, sizeForViewAtIndexPath indexPath:IndexPath) -> Int
    //  Returns the amount of columns that have to display at that moment
    func numberOfColumnsInCollectionView(collectionView:UICollectionView) ->Int
}

class FillingLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {
    weak var delegate: FillingLayoutDelegate!

    fileprivate var cellPadding: CGFloat = 10

    fileprivate var cache = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

    fileprivate var contentHeight: CGFloat = 0
    private var columsHeights : [CGFloat] = []
    private var avaiableSpaces : [(Int,CGFloat)] = []

    fileprivate var contentWidth: CGFloat {
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else {
            return 0
        }
        let insets = collectionView.contentInset
        return collectionView.bounds.width - (insets.left + insets.right)
    }

    var columnsQuantity : Int{
        get{
            if(self.delegate != nil)
            {
                return (self.delegate?.numberOfColumnsInCollectionView(collectionView: self.collectionView!))!
            }
            return 0
        }
    }

    //MARK: PRIVATE METHODS
    private func shortestColumnIndex() -> Int{
        var retVal : Int = 0
        var shortestValue = MAXFLOAT

        var i = 0
        for columnHeight in columsHeights {
            //debugPrint("Column Height: \(columnHeight) index: \(i)")
            if(Float(columnHeight) < shortestValue)
            {
                shortestValue = Float(columnHeight)
                retVal = i
            }
            i += 1
        }
        //debugPrint("shortest Column index: \(retVal)")
        return retVal
    }

    //MARK: PRIVATE METHODS
    private func largestColumnIndex() -> Int{
        var retVal : Int = 0
        var largestValue : Float = 0.0

        var i = 0
        for columnHeight in columsHeights {
            //debugPrint("Column Height: \(columnHeight) index: \(i)")
            if(Float(columnHeight) > largestValue)
            {
                largestValue = Float(columnHeight)
                retVal = i
            }
            i += 1
        }
        //debugPrint("shortest Column index: \(retVal)")
        return retVal
    }

    private func canUseBigColumnOnIndex(columnIndex:Int,size:Int) ->Bool
    {
        if(columnIndex < self.columnsQuantity - (size-1))
        {
            let firstColumnHeight = columsHeights[columnIndex]
            for i in columnIndex..<columnIndex + size{
                if(firstColumnHeight != columsHeights[i]) {
                    return false
                }
            }
            return true
        }

        return false
    }

    override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: contentHeight)
    }

    override func prepare() {
        // Check if cache is empty
        guard cache.isEmpty == true, let collectionView = collectionView else {
            return
        }

        //  Set all column heights to 0
        self.columsHeights = []
        for _ in 0..<self.columnsQuantity {
            self.columsHeights.append(0)
        }

        for item in 0 ..< collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) {

            let indexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: 0)

            let viewSize: Int = delegate.collectionView(collectionView, sizeForViewAtIndexPath: indexPath)
            let blockWidth = (contentWidth/CGFloat(columnsQuantity))
            let width = blockWidth * CGFloat(viewSize)
            let height = width

            var columIndex = self.shortestColumnIndex()
            var xOffset = (contentWidth/CGFloat(columnsQuantity)) * CGFloat(columIndex)
            var yOffset = self.columsHeights[columIndex]

            if(viewSize > 1){//Big Cell
                if(!self.canUseBigColumnOnIndex(columnIndex: columIndex,size: viewSize)){
                    //  Set column height
                    for i in columIndex..<columIndex + viewSize{
                        if(i < columnsQuantity){
                            self.avaiableSpaces.append((i,yOffset))
                            self.columsHeights[i] += blockWidth
                        }
                    }
                    //  Set column height
                    yOffset = columsHeights[largestColumnIndex()]
                    xOffset = 0
                    columIndex = 0
                }

                for i in columIndex..<columIndex + viewSize{
                    if(i < columnsQuantity){
                        //current height
                        let currValue = self.columsHeights[i]
                        //new column height with the update
                        let newValue = yOffset + height
                        //space that will remaing in blank, this must be 0 if its ok
                        let remainder = (newValue - currValue) - CGFloat(viewSize) * blockWidth
                        if(remainder > 0) {
                            debugPrint("Its bigger remainder is \(remainder)")
                            //number of spaces to fill
                            let spacesTofillInColumn = Int(remainder/blockWidth)
                            //we need to add those spaces as avaiableSpaces
                            for j in 0..<spacesTofillInColumn {
                                self.avaiableSpaces.append((i,currValue + (CGFloat(j)*blockWidth)))
                            }
                        }
                        self.columsHeights[i] = yOffset + height
                    }
                }
            }else{
                //if there is not avaiable space
                if(self.avaiableSpaces.count == 0)
                {
                    //  Set column height
                    self.columsHeights[columIndex] += height
                }else{//if there is some avaiable space
                    yOffset = self.avaiableSpaces.first!.1
                    xOffset = CGFloat(self.avaiableSpaces.first!.0) * width
                    self.avaiableSpaces.remove(at: 0)
                }
            }

            print(width)

            let frame = CGRect(x: xOffset, y: yOffset, width: width, height: height)
            let insetFrame = frame.insetBy(dx: cellPadding, dy: cellPadding)

            let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)
            attributes.frame = insetFrame
            cache.append(attributes)

            contentHeight = max(contentHeight, frame.maxY)
        }
    }

    func getNextCellSize(currentCell: Int, collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        var nextViewSize = 0
        if currentCell < (collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) - 1) {
            nextViewSize = delegate.collectionView(collectionView, sizeForViewAtIndexPath: IndexPath(item: currentCell + 1, section: 0))
        }
        return nextViewSize
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {

        var visibleLayoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

        // Loop through the cache and look for items in the rect
        for attributes in cache {
            if attributes.frame.intersects(rect) {
                visibleLayoutAttributes.append(attributes)
            }
        }
        return visibleLayoutAttributes
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        return cache[indexPath.item]
    }
}
```

## UPDATED

**You need to setup your viewController as FillingLayoutDelegate**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    if let layout = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? FillingLayout
    {
        layout.delegate = self
    }

}
```

**FillingLayoutDelegate implementation in your ViewController**

```
extension ViewController: FillingLayoutDelegate{
func collectionView(_ collectionView:UICollectionView,sizeForViewAtIndexPath indexPath:IndexPath) ->Int{
        if(indexPath.row == 0 || indexPath.row == 4)
        {
            return 2
        }

        if(indexPath.row == 5)
        {
            return 3
        }

        return 1
    }

    func numberOfColumnsInCollectionView(collectionView:UICollectionView) ->Int{
        return 3
    }
}
```

**ScreenShot working**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use `UICollectionViewLayout` to handle this. Code is given below:

`UICollectionViewLayout` class to define layout:

```
class CustomCircularCollectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {

var itemSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 150)
var attributesList = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

override func prepare() {
    super.prepare()

    let itemNo = collectionView?.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) ?? 0
    let length = (collectionView!.frame.width - 40)/3
    itemSize = CGSize(width: length, height: length)

    attributesList = (0..<itemNo).map { (i) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes in
        let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: IndexPath(item: i, section: 0))

        attributes.size = self.itemSize

        var x = CGFloat(i%3)*(itemSize.width+10) + 10
        var y = CGFloat(i/3)*(itemSize.width+10) + 10

        if i > 2 {
            y += (itemSize.width+10)
            attributes.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: itemSize.width, height: itemSize.height)
        } else if i == 0 {
            attributes.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: itemSize.width*2+10, height: itemSize.height*2+10)
        } else {
            x = itemSize.width*2 + 30
            if i == 2 {
                y += itemSize.height + 10
            }
            attributes.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: itemSize.width, height: itemSize.height)
        }

        return attributes
    }
}

override var collectionViewContentSize : CGSize {

    return CGSize(width: collectionView!.bounds.width, height: (itemSize.height + 10)*CGFloat(ceil(Double(collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: 0))/3))+(itemSize.height + 20))

}

override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    return attributesList
}
override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
    if indexPath.row < attributesList.count
    {
        return attributesList[indexPath.row]
    }
    return nil
}
override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Now set this class as your collection view layout:

```
self.collectionView!.collectionViewLayout = circularLayoutObject
```

This will display your grid as given below:
[image]

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: It works well. Thank you so much! ^^