# Custom layout using UICollectionView in Landscape and Portrait

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, orientation, uicollectionviewcell

Is there a way to rearrange the cells between portrait and landscape using UICollectionView in a way like the following image? Just to be clear, little square on landscape remains on the left side and the biggest one goes to the right.

[image]

**EDIT**

My problem is that in Landscape mode the big square must occupy and fill two rows

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48905355/collectionview-flowlayout-customize/48908379#48908379 maybe can help you

Comment: What’s the question? Is it whether landscape and portrait layouts can differ? Of course they can.

Comment: I think he is asking about how to do it, more than if is possible or not @matt, how to define a custom LayoutFlow on UICollectionView and how change it after orientation change, OP can correct me if I am wrong

Comment: My problem is that in Landscape mode the big square must occupy and fill two rows

Comment: @ReinierMelianI I've read the post I think this is the right answer thx.