# Random UICollectionView grid

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm about to do my first **UICollectionView** and from a syntax point of view it looks almost exactly the same as what you would do for a **UITableView**.

I'm trying to figure out how I could build a photo grid that is based on the image below.

[image]

Can this be achieved with a single UICollectionview, or do I need to do a static view for the big images and then two collectionViews beside it (yuck!) or can this be done with sections?

Comment: Your title talks about "Random" but not your question text. How do you know how will look like your UICollectionView (size, which indexPath, etc.)? You need a Custom UIColelctionViewLayout, you can check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186246/uicollectionview-layout-like-snapchat

Comment: @Larme I hope eventually it will be based on a random arrangement of 1x, 2x, 3x and 4x grid allocations - but I guess I understand what you are saying, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using a single collection view. You can customize your collection view using `UICollectionViewLayout`. `UICollectionViewLayout` is very powerful, and you can achieve almost every kind of layout with this. Here's a very in-depth tutorial explaining the `UICollectionViewLayout`. Understand it and change it to according to your needs.
[Link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/392-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest)

Comment: Fantastic thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!