# How to add a UIPageController and UICollectionViewController to a UIViewController programmatically

Tags: swift, uiview, uicollectionview, uipageviewcontroller

I already have a UIViewController made programmatically, and would like at the bottom to have a collection view with 4 cells, but I want to be able to swipe through different pages of the collection view to see different cells. I'm not sure where to begin with this wether to enable paging on the collection view and how that would work with setting up the cells, or to create a page controller and adding the collection view to that? There are a couple of ways that I have seen online already, but that don't really fit my needs.

I would like something as such:

[image]

Let me know if I can provide you with more information. I just created a basic page controller but am not sure how to achieve what I'm looking for.

**Edit:** I created a collection view and added the constraints to get the layout I want; however I'm not sure how to make it swipe like a page.

Here's the code for the collection view:

```
let friendsCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cv.register(FriendsCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    cv.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    cv.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    return cv
}()

view.addSubview(friendsCollectionView)
friendsCollectionView.anchor(top: separatorView.bottomAnchor, left: nil, bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: 50, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 250, height: 250)
 friendsCollectionView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 75, height: 75)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    if section == 0 {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 85, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }
    if section == 1 {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
    }
    if section == 2 {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 85, left: 5, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }


    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0 { return 1 }
        if section == 1 { return 2 }
        if section == 2 { return 1 }


    return 0
}
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 3
}
```

Comment: “ but I want to be able to swipe through different pages of the collection view to see different cells” unclear what the means. Do you mean each page is a collection of four different cells?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Okay so then what does this have to do with collection views? Your page view controller pages are separate view controllers! They are not parts of a single view such as a collection view. You just want a view controller containing four images in a diamond shape, to function as your page.

Comment: I am confused as to what you are having issues with ? Have you tried to do this at all? Have you tried any code yourself? To me it seems fairly straight forward to implement what you need, but It is difficult to provide you with an accurate answer as it seems you have not tried to implement any of these yourself.. a simple google search...how to add uicollection view programatically... would yield the answer

Comment: Yes I have tried, and nothing has shown up. The reason that I was trying to do a collection view was because I also want to implement a circular animation so the four cells would rotate in a circular motion, and then bounce back, unless that's easily achievable by a normal view controller. I also was thinking to have a collection view because it would be easier pulling the values from the database that way so I can minimize my database storage.

Answer (score 2):

All you need would be a UICollectionViewController or as I am assuming you have, a UIViewController that conforms to the collectionView protocols. Your UIViewController with one UICollectionView is a good starting point. However the cell you insert needs to be different. First of all, the collectionView within the ViewController needs to have **collectionView?.isPagingEnabled = true** and its layouts **scrollDirection** set to **.horizontal**. Having done that you need to create your cells.

The cells you implement should be a subclass of **UICollectionViewController** and **UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout**. This collectionView's layout needs to have **scrollDirection** set to **.vertical** although I believe you are not scrolling in this view anyways. The number of cells in this collectionView will be 4. You then **dequeue** your cell of which you want to have 4 (the one with the head in white on blue).

The **UICollectionViewController** needs to then be **dequeued** as the cell for your first collectionView. Basically:

Your main **ViewController** has a collectionView that scrolls horizontally. This collectionView has a **UICollectionViewController** as cells and scrolls vertically.

It may sound very complicated but I have done it and it works smoothly. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm pretty new to CollectionViews. What do you mean by the cell of the first collection view? Do I have multiple for this or how does that work with the cells with the layout I'm looking for? I'm not sure how to make it so that each cell has a different placement. I've only ever built out a collection view where everything is layed out the same like a TableView. Your help is much appreciated thank you!

Comment: You could use sections and items (they are like rows and columns). So for example for row one you would only have 1 column and one cell. Then for row two, you would have two columns and two cells, side by side. For the last row you then again have only one column and one cell.

Comment: I will try to explain what I meant by "the cell of the first collectionView". Each collectionView needs cells registered and dequeued by it. You have one collectionView with 3 items that is there to scroll horizontally. To this horizontal collectionView, you register a cell. This cell is a collectionViewController and is where you register your "white face with blue background cells". In your case creating a custom layout could be beneficially on which you can read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186246/uicollectionview-layout-like-snapchat/43409440#43409440

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was able to make the collection view; however I'm not sure how to make it scroll horizontally and in a page like fashion so that it snaps when you swipe. Also how do I add the additional cells besides just the 4 that you see so that when you swipe it looks like in the mockup.