# Have cells with data and empty cells in collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

So what I have is a collection view that looks as [such](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58125895/how-to-add-a-uipagecontroller-and-uicollectionviewcontroller-to-a-uiviewcontroll). I have a set amount of cells that I want in the collection view, 16. So if there aren't enough of the user's friends (data for the collection view), then I would like the remaining cells from the 16 to just be empty and be able to get a different functionality from tapping the "empty" cells.

**Edit:**

I was able to fix the crash on `numberOfItemsInSection`. What I tried to do, and what somewhat works but not exactly and not if there are more than one real favorite, it will only show the cell image of the first one, but when tapped will take me to the view of the correct user as it should. I appended the actual favorites to an array `favorites` then determined the amount of fake users there should be and added those to `fakeFavorites` and at the end combined both of them to equal 16. What happens is I get all of the cells except the sections with 2 items in it showing the real user (the first in the array)

Here is the code:

```
var favorites: [FUser] = []
var fakeFavorites: [FUser] = []
var allFavorites: [FUser] = []
@objc var favoriteId: [String] = []
var count: Int!
var remaining: Int!

let friendCellId = "friendCellID"

var user: FUser!

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 75, height: 75)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    if section == 0 {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 85, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }
    if section == 1 {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
    }
    if section == 2 {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 85, left: 5, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }
    if section == 3 {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 85, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }
    if section == 4 {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
    }
    if section == 5 {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 85, left: 5, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }
    if section == 6 {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 85, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }
    if section == 7 {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
    }
    if section == 8 {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 85, left: 5, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }
    if section == 9 {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 85, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }
    if section == 10 {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
    }
    if section == 11 {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 85, left: 5, bottom: 0, right: 10)
    }


    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
}



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 { return 1 }
    if section == 1 { return 2 }
    if section == 2 { return 1 }
    if section == 3 { return 1 }
    if section == 4 { return 2 }
    if section == 5 { return 1 }
    if section == 6 { return 1 }
    if section == 7 { return 2 }
    if section == 8 { return 1 }
    if section == 9 { return 1 }
    if section == 10 { return 2 }
    if section == 11 { return 1 }


    return allFavorites.count
}



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! FriendsCell


    var favorite: FUser

    if allFavorites.count == 16 {
        favorite = allFavorites[indexPath.row]
        cell.bindData(friend: favorite)
        cell.profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 37.5
        cell.profileImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true

    }

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let favorite = allFavorites[indexPath.row]
    if favorite.objectId == "CjEIGXRDb6hqIYDrTwBbkOlBjzR2" {
        print("Fake user! ")
    } else {
        let otherProfileView = OtherProfileView()
        otherProfileView.user = favorite
        navigationController?.pushViewController(otherProfileView, animated: true)
    }
}



func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 12

}

func loadFavorites() {
    cleanup()


           let favoriteIds = FUser.currentUser()!.favorites

           if favoriteIds.count > 0 {

               for favoriteId in favoriteIds {

                   firebase.child(kUSER).queryOrdered(byChild: kOBJECTID).queryEqual(toValue: favoriteId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in

                       if snapshot.exists() {
                           let userDictionary = ((snapshot.value as! NSDictionary).allValues as Array).first

                           let fuser = FUser.init(_dictionary: userDictionary as! NSDictionary)

                           self.favorites.append(fuser)
                           self.favoriteId.append(fuser.objectId)
                        self.count = self.favorites.count
                        self.remaining = 16 - self.count


                        if self.remaining > 0 {
                            self.createFakeUser(countFake: self.remaining)

                        }
                       }
                    self.friendsCollectionView.reloadData()

                   }

               }

           } else {
               print("There are no favorites!")

           }
}

func createFakeUser(countFake: Int) {

    let fakeUserId = "CjEIGXRDb6hqIYDrTwBbkOlBjzR2"

    firebase.child(kUSER).queryOrdered(byChild: kOBJECTID).queryEqual(toValue: fakeUserId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            let userDictionary = ((snapshot.value as! NSDictionary).allValues as Array).first
            let fuser = FUser.init(_dictionary: userDictionary as! NSDictionary)
            print("How many fake users to create: \(countFake)")
            self.fakeFavorites.append(contentsOf: repeatElement(fuser, count: countFake))
            self.allFavorites.append(contentsOf: self.favorites)
            self.allFavorites.append(contentsOf: self.fakeFavorites)
            print("Total amount of all favorites: \(self.allFavorites.count)")
        }
    }
}


   @objc func cleanup() {
    favoriteId.removeAll()
    favorites.removeAll()
    fakeFavorites.removeAll()
    allFavorites.removeAll()
    friendsCollectionView.reloadData()
  }'
```

I'm not exaclty sure how to solve this problem. It seems really simple and close but I can't put my finger on it. If you have any improvements from what I currently have to feel free to let me know!

All help is much appreciated!

Comment: What about using a creating a fake `FUser` that you'll add to `self.favorites` until you get 16 ones, and if it's a fake one, have a different behavior?

Comment: @Larme that’s a good idea I didn’t think about! Could you provide an example on how to do so?

Comment: In `FUser`, add a property: `let isFake: Bool` , and a factory method: static func makeFake() -> FUser { //Call an init where you set the isFake to true } And add them.

Comment: @Larme How would this work when adding new favorites, and therefore deleting/replacing the place holder "fake" ones? Would you be able to give a coded example or answer on how I would swap it out?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly what you want to do is to display 16 items in your collection view and as new datas come in you'd like to replace the empty items with real DB entries. If so you can do it like this:

```
// FUser
class FUser {
   var id: Int = 0    // Default id value for FUser
   ...
}
```

Here are some things to consider while implementing this approach:

- If you are using a MySQL DB then default `id` value for `FUser` can be `0`. Since MySQL will start the ids from 1 and auto increment the value for new entries.
- If you are using a Mongo DB then default `id` value for `FUser` can be `''`(empty string).

Since you have different amount of cells in each section rather than going with a favorites `Array` you can try using a `Dictionary`.

```
// Create a favorites dictionary
var favorites: [Int: [FUser]] = [:] // key = section number, value = section items
favorites[0] = [FUser()]
favorites[1] = [FUser(), FUser()]
...

friendsCollectionView.reloadData()
```

Now that you are using a dictionary you can replace the `numberOfItemsInSection` code with this:

```
// numberOfItemsInSection
return favorites[section]!.count
```

Also it becomes a lot easier to get the data for cell at `cellForItemAt` function.

```
// cellForItemAt
var favorite = favories[indexPath.section]![indexPath.row]

if favorite.id == 0 { // This should become an empty cell
   let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "emptyCell", for: indexPath) as! EmptyCell
   // configure cell
   return cell
} else { // We got ourselves a friend, yay!
   let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! FriendsCell
   // configure cell
   return cell
}

return cell
```

And lastly the did select part:

```
// didSelectItemAt
let favorite = favorites[indexPath.section]![indexPath.row]
if favorite.id == 0 {
   // Do the empty action
} else {
   // Do the friend action
}
```

So this way you are able to control how many items will be displayed in each section via favorites dictionary. You don't need to change the configuration at `cellForRowAt`, `didSelectItemAt` etc. functions when you make changes at `numberOfItemsInSection`. Also since you can distinguish a real `FUser` from a dummy one you can implement the empty state actions. The only thing that you require to do is to change how `favorites` dictionary is created. In the above code I put dummy `FUser` datas without checking if an API call has fetched real `FUser`s. Add that control to the code and you should be fine.

Comment: I’m using Firebase. Will this work the same or how would I modify it to do so?

Comment: It would work the same, just fetch your data from Firebase and add them to `favorites` as you'd like.

Comment: this sounds exactly what I want to do after a more thorough look. There's one thing that I'm confused about though. Can you explain what the 'id' is and what it does or means?

Comment: Also, just to be clear going with this approach would keep the desired layout I want?

Comment: `id` is an identifier for each entry you have in your DB. You should be able to distinguish `FUser`s from one another. The layout will also be as you desired since the code I wrote doesn't make any changes on how the UI is created.

Comment: Do you happen to have a solution based on the edits I just made? I'd prefer to try and do it the way I had it set up since it follows what I've done on other parts of the project. The ObjectId is what's unique for each user which is a string value. I really appreciate your help!