# swift 4 set cells with different heights and width on the same UICollectionView vertical flow

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make images grid like the below image
[image]

I tried the below code

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource  {
@IBOutlet weak var collectionViw: UICollectionView!

var widthss = [59.0,59.0,59.0,121.0,59.0,59.0,59.0,59.0,59.0,59.0,28.0,28.0,59.0,59.0,] as [CGFloat]
var heights = [36.0,36.0,36.0,76.0,36.0,76.0,36.0,36.0,36.0,76.0,36.0,36.0,36.0,76.0,] as [CGFloat]
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return heights.count
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! UICustomCollectionViewCell
    // Customize cell height
    cell.frame = CGRect(x: cell.frame.origin.x, y: cell.frame.origin.y , width: widthss[indexPath.row], height: heights[indexPath.row])

    return cell
    }




}
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {


    return CGSize(width: widthss[indexPath.row], height: heights[indexPath.row])
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {return 1.0
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout
    collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 1.0
}}
```

at the end, i found the result like the below image,
[image]

what I need is to make the collection view cells like the first image
Anyone have an idea where is my mistake
thanks in advance

Comment: I think probably you'r looking for this -> https://stablekernel.com/creating-a-custom-uicollectionviewlayout-in-swift/

Comment: You need a custom Flow Layout. because the method you currently have can interact only in cell size, but not in cell rect. So it can't decide where to fit it, it just put them the one after the other one. Note, that having two array (one for heigh, one for size), is not recommended. Use only one array of CGSize instead. Custom Layout logic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186246/uicollectionview-layout-like-snapchat And `cell.frame = ...` won't work in your code, it's the CollectionView Layout that sets it.