# Swift IOS - a complex table view cells' arrangement

Tags: swift

All. I am new to Swift. I am trying to create something similar to the image attached below. My question is regarding the table view.

I create a prototype cell for each recipe, in which contains an image View and a textfield. However, how should I arrange those cells like those in the picture attached?

It seems that each cell has a different height. I thought about including multiple recipes in one prototype cell, yet it may not be the right solution.

In the real world, how do people handle such arrangements? Maybe people use something other than prototype cell?

Your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: That's more like a UICollectionView, with a custom Flow Layout. There is a repetitve layout (each 4 ones, I guess), you can see logic there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186246/uicollectionview-layout-like-snapchat

Comment: @Larme Thanks!!! I am googling UICollectionView now.

Comment: you can refer this https://www.raywenderlich.com/4829472-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest

Comment: @RuchiMakadia The tutorial is super helpful. I have finished the page. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this thing by using `collectionview`. If you know width and hight in advance then you can simply create `collectionview` with constant width and height of cell. if you don't know the dimensions in advance you need to do some extra task in `collectionview` which is [selfsizingcell](https://medium.com/@aqeel.ahmad406796/collectionview-self-sizing-cell-swift-ae36dfab26f).

Answer (score 0):

This is called 'waterfall collection view', you can find similar thing in Pinterest app. Size of each cell is dynamically calculated based on the width&height of picture itself.
Personally I've used this [open-source github project](https://github.com/chiahsien/CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout), in order to implement same thing in my app.