# Collectionview Second item starts from centre instead of Top

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to copy the search layout of Instagram for the collectionview. I have tried doing it but my second item starts from the center instead of top which is causing the problem.

Actual Output: [image: Actual Output]

Expected Outlput: [image: Expected Output]

Here is my code

```
extension UIViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{



public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 12
}

public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CVCell", for: indexPath) as! CVCell
    cell.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    cell.lbl.text = "\(indexPath.item)"
    cell.lbl.textAlignment = .center
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.5

    return cell

}

public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if indexPath.item == 0{
        return CGSize(width: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 3) * 2, height: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 3) * 2)
    }
    return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 3, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 3)
}
```

Comment: The down-voter probably should have pointed out in a comment that question requires more info about what was tried, what generated the non-working output.

Comment: The flow layout tries to lay the content out horizontally, wrapping to the next row as necessary. That's why the OP attempt isn't filling vertical space.  Flow layout can be subclassed, though, to adjust.  See the "Mosaic" layout described here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/customizing_collection_view_layouts

Comment: That's normal. You need a custom FlowLayout. See an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186246/uicollectionview-layout-like-snapchat