# Custom layout 1 large 2 small cells UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

I want to create a layout like this image below but having trouble understanding how flow layout can be used to achieve this kind of layout

[image]

Basically what I want is 1 large picture than 2 small pictures right to it,
Then from index 3,4,5... and so on will be a 3 images grid. Only the First 3 cells will have a different layout. Does anyone know how we can achieve this kind of Layout in collectionView?

**Update Code for collectionView**

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 100;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    AppDelegate* delegate = [AppDelegate applicationDelegate];
    FriendsListCell *cell= (FriendsListCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kFriendsListCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
   
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    return cell;
}



- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeZero;
    newSize.height = 100;  // use your prefered size
    newSize.width = 100;   // use your prefered size

    if(indexPath.item == 0) // set custom size for the first item
    {
        newSize.width = 200;  // use your prefered size
        newSize.height = 200; // use your prefered size
    }
    return newSize;
}
```

Comment: You can't achieve that behavior with default FlowLayout. You need a custom one. Some explainations: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186246/uicollectionview-layout-like-snapchat

Comment: @Larme can you explain the logic. I want the first 3 cells like above and then rest of cells will be 3 cells in a row

Comment: You need to create your own Custom Flow Layout. It should know the frames (and not only the sizes) of each items.

Comment: @Larme do you have a sample code on GitHub for your answer to the other question?

Answer (score 1):

You have to customiz the `width` and `height` of `collectionview` items according to the index .

like the follwoing:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let width : CGFloat
        let height : CGFloat
        if indexPath.item == 0 { // set custom size for the first item
            width = 200 // use your prefered size
            height = 200 // use your prefered size
        } else {
            width = 100 // use your prefered size
            height = 100 // use your prefered size
        }
        return CGSizeMake(width, height)
}
```

and don't forgot to `conform` the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`

For **`Objective-c`**

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeZero;
    newSize.height = 100;  // use your prefered size
    newSize.width = 100;   // use your prefered size

    if(indexPath.item == 0) // set custom size for the first item
    {
        newSize.width = 200;  // use your prefered size
        newSize.height = 200; // use your prefered size
    }
    return newSize;
}
```

Update screenshot
[image]

Comment: I just put the sample code, the way you can do it.

Comment: The layout looks simple but it's not a simple thing like passing width and height. If I pass width and height then where 2nd item will be placed?

Comment: see the code and think about.
when first item take width and height 200. means your 2nd item will be placed after that.

Comment: I assume your phone screen is 347. if first item takes 200 width then 2nd item should take place after first item as 2nd item with is 100.

Comment: I think you messed up with `collectionview` configuration(size, orientation etc) and item size.

Comment: ok let me send you screenshot for first 3 items

Comment: Updated your answer with screenshot

Comment: Updated original post

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C:

```
@interface MyFlowLayoutObjC()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *cellsLayout;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGSize computedContentSize;
@end

@implementation MyFlowLayoutObjC

-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _cellsLayout = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }
    return  self;
}
-(void)prepareLayout {
    [super prepareLayout];

    [self setComputedContentSize:CGSizeZero];

    [[self cellsLayout] removeAllObjects];
    CGSize fullFrameSize = [[self collectionView] frame].size;
    NSUInteger numberOfitems = [[self collectionView] numberOfItemsInSection:0];
    CGSize unitSize = CGSizeMake(fullFrameSize.width / 3.0, fullFrameSize.width / 3.0);
    for (NSUInteger anIndex = 0; anIndex < numberOfitems; anIndex ++) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:anIndex inSection:0];
        UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForCellWithIndexPath:indexPath];
        switch (anIndex) {
            case 0:
                [attributes setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, unitSize.width * 2, unitSize.height * 2)];
                break;
            case 1:
                [attributes setFrame:CGRectMake(unitSize.width * 2, 0, unitSize.width, unitSize.height)];
                break;
            case 2:
                [attributes setFrame:CGRectMake(unitSize.width * 2, unitSize.height, unitSize.width, unitSize.height)];
                break;
            default:
                [attributes setFrame:CGRectMake(unitSize.width  * (anIndex % 3), unitSize.height * (CGFloat)((anIndex / 3) + 1), unitSize.width, unitSize.height)];
                break;
        }
        [[self cellsLayout] setObject:attributes forKey:indexPath];
        [self setComputedContentSize:CGSizeMake(MAX([attributes frame].origin.x + [attributes frame].size.width, [self computedContentSize].width),
                                                MAX([attributes frame].origin.y + [attributes frame].size.height, [self computedContentSize].height))];
    }
}

-(NSArray<__kindof UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *> *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSArray *layouts = [[self cellsLayout] allValues];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes * _Nullable aLayout, NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * _Nullable bindings) {
        return CGRectIntersectsRect([aLayout frame], rect);
    }];
    return [layouts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
}

-(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return [self cellsLayout][indexPath];
}

- (CGSize)collectionViewContentSize {
    return [self computedContentSize];
}

@end
```

And in Swift:

```
class MyFlowLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {

    private var cellsLayout: [IndexPath: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = [:]
    
    override func prepare() {
        cellsLayout.removeAll()

        guard let fullFrameSizeWidth = collectionView?.frame.size else { return }
        guard let numberOfItems = collectionView?.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) else { return }
        let unitSize = CGSize(width: fullFrameSizeWidth.width / 3.0, height: fullFrameSizeWidth.width / 3.0)
        for anIndex in 0..<numberOfItems {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(item: anIndex, section: 0)
            let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)
            switch anIndex {
            case 0:
                attributes.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: unitSize.width * 2, height: unitSize.height * 2))
            case 1:
                attributes.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: unitSize.width * 2, y: 0), size: unitSize)
            case 2:
                attributes.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: unitSize.width * 2, y: unitSize.height), size: unitSize)
            default:
                attributes.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: unitSize.width  * CGFloat(anIndex % 3),
                                                          y: unitSize.height * CGFloat(Int(anIndex / 3) + 1)),
                                          size: unitSize)
            }
            cellsLayout[indexPath] = attributes
        }

    }

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        return cellsLayout.compactMap { $0.value.frame.intersects(rect) ? $0.value : nil }
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        return cellsLayout[indexPath]
    }

    override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: cellsLayout.max(by: { $0.1.frame.maxX < $1.1.frame.maxX })?.value.frame.maxX ?? 0,
                      height: cellsLayout.max(by: { $0.1.frame.maxY < $1.1.frame.maxY })?.value.frame.maxY ?? 0)
    }
}
```

This should do the trick.

Now, let's explain, you need a custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. Because with just overriding `-collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:`, you can't do that. It will get the size of the first item, put it in the frame. Then, get the frame of the second item, put it at its right if it's fits, else under it, etc.
When everything is set, it will center on y axis for each line. That's why you have this behavior.

So what's needed?

Let's override `-layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:` to return the layouts for each cells which intersect with the rect (which is the visible rect).
In order to do so, we need to know theses frame, so I made de needed calculations in `-prepareLayout`.

Comment: Thanks Larme. I have one more question can I drop an email to you ?

Comment: If you have a development question, prefer using StackOverflow, that way, everyone can interacts, responds, but also learn things.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I am stuck somewhere and I want to know ASAP.

Comment: And I don't know everything, other might interacts quickly, with better answer. I answers when I have the solution AND it interests me.

Comment: yeah I've posted it here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66766177/rest-api-post-call-is-failing-when-app-in-background