# Rest API post call is failing when app in background

Tags: objective-c, rest, background, afnetworking

I'm using AWS Transfer Utility to upload media to the S3 bucket and it's working fine in the background but after the media upload, I have to call a REST API (POST) call to my server which is failing when the app is in the background. How can I call rest API when the app is in the background?

Here is my code

```
- (void)didUploadedAllMedias:(BOOL)yesOrNo {
    
    if (yesOrNo) {
        UIApplicationState state = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState];
        if (state == UIApplicationStateBackground){
            [self notifyUserForMedia:YES];
        }
        self.postStatus = BG_SERVICE_STATUS_FINISHING_UP;
        
        if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(finishingUP)]) {
            [self.delegate finishingUP];
            [self executeWebServiceCall];
            
        }
        
    }
    else {
        self.postStatus = BG_SERVICE_STATUS_ERROR;
        UIApplicationState state = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState];
        if (state == UIApplicationStateBackground){
            [self notifyUserForMedia:YES];
        }
    }
    
}


- (void)executeWebServiceCall {
    
    UIApplicationState state = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState];
    if (state == UIApplicationStateBackground){
        __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
        
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            __strong typeof(weakSelf) strongSelf = weakSelf;
            if(strongSelf){
                [strongSelf submitPost];
            }
            
        });
    }else {
        __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            __strong typeof(weakSelf) strongSelf = weakSelf;
            if(strongSelf){
                [strongSelf submitPost];
            }
            
        });
    }
    
}
```

On the foreground, it works perfectly fine. In the background, it's like waiting for the app to come in the foreground and executed automatically, and sometimes the request timed out.

Comment: I understand you make 2 calls - one to upload and one when done. I think you will need to change it a bit. When app goes in background ongoing upload will (probably) finish if you do it correct but then iOS will not allow further calls until app comes back to foreground. You probably need to reduce it to just a single call or else maybe ```UIApplication.sharedApplication.idleTimerDisabled``` can help you.

Comment: The issue is sometimes it works. Also I am using AWS for upload and then updating on my server. So I cannot combine these two. Also I'm using AFNetworking for rest calls.

Comment: I think it works sometimes because it completes before the app is put to sleep. Try that ```BOOL``` I mentioned. Set it to ```YES``` when you make the first call and to ```NO``` when the whole thing is done and see how it goes.

Comment: Sounds like you are running out of the time (used to be set to approximately 30 seconds - check the Docs to see current specs) ... "sometimes it works / sometimes it doesn't". You need to either optimize this (compress the data, make a single invocation, etc., etc,. etc.), or persist the data and when you become active/foreground again, then perform the upload/complete the upload.

Comment: Upload is running smooth only issue I'm getting is with rest api call